# Can smart hubs such as Samsung SmartThings produce audio?

Tags: smart-home, zigbee, samsung-smartthings, wink-hub

I'm looking at some ZigBee smart hubs but once you have one how can you add audio to them? So if a pit goes off at night it makes a sound? Or if a fire alarm is triggered?

The smart hubs I've been considering are:

- The [Wink Hub](https://www.wink.com)
- [Samsung SmartThings](http://www.samsung.com/smartthings)

Can these hubs produce audio as required?

Answer (score 2):

[SmartThings supports speakers](https://www.smartthings.com/products/-/filter/categories/speakers) which can make announcements. As of today, you can even [use Echo devices for it](https://community.smartthings.com/t/release-echo-speaks/142252/1907).